# R: Drop multiple levels in list from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm looking to drop multiple levels of a variable based on values in a list. My actual variable has 300 levels, but the below code creates a smaller sample data frame with a similar structure.

```
species <- data.frame(c("onmy","lema","misa","icpu","onmy","lema","misa","icpu","pyov", "tacl"),c("1","2","4","5","3","1","8","10","0", "26"))
colnames(species) <- c("species","count" )
```

I can keep values in a data frame based on a list using the following code.

```
keep <- data.frame(species[ species$species %in% c("onmy","lema","misa","icpu"), ]) # Keeps desired species in list
```

For my current purpose listing levels to keep will not work because I would have to list ~ 100 levels. However, I can drop several levels by repeating the following line of code repeatedly only changing the level value.

```
keep2 <- droplevels(species[-which(species$species == "pyov"),])
keep2 <- droplevels(keep2[-which(keep2$species == "tacl"),])
```

However, this is not a very clean way of writing the code. Is there a way to drop levels of a variable based on a list that is similar to the way I keep value in the second code block? I've seen a lot of examples, but I haven't found anything that fits my case use

**Edit:**
I want to feed it the list c("tacl", "pyov") and have it drop the levels I listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%` instead of `==`

```
droplevels( subset(species, species %in% levels(keep$species)))
```

---

Or if we want to enter a vector of values

```
droplevels(subset(species, !species %in% c("tacl", "pyov")))
```

Comment: droplevels( subset(species, species %in% keep$species)) doesnt work for my purposes it would require me to type out all the levels i want to keep like  I did the second code block. In my actual data it would require a list of 98  values.  I want to feed it the list c("tacl", "pyov") and have it drop the levels i listed.

Comment: @DevonOliver Do you need `levels(keep$species)` instead of `keep$species`

Comment: your answer triggered something in my head. This give me the output I need droplevels( species[!species$species %in% c("pyov","tacl"),]) . If change your response I will accept

Comment: @DevonOliver I already changed it.  `subset` would be better compared to `[` as it wouldn't drop the dimenstions automatically when encounter a single row or column